# Issue with automatic Sonar issues assign

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 5.2 with Perforce plugin and LDAP.
Sonar-runner is running via Jenkins and triggered when project build completed.
When i'm looking in SonarQube GUI, i see that some of the issues are assigned correctly to the developers who check in the code but most of the issues are not assigned.
Any suggestion why? How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It was because some users didn't exist in SonarQube. Even having a LDAP connection for authorization, they needed to do a first login in the system to appear in the list of users.

To check if it is your problem click in Administration → Users and see if your non assigned user is in the list of users:
[image: Find users]

If he isn't present, tell him to do a login and he should appear there. The automatic assignment will work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Issues are automatically assigned to user :

- For issue defined on a line, it is assigned to the user by finding the one having its login, email or SCM accounts matching the author of the line

  - For issue defined on a file, it is assigned the the last committer of the file
  - If no user can be find, then issues are assigned to the default of the project if set (sonar.issues.defaultAssigneeLogin)